# Use UI thread to display toast messages?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, toast

I have a listener that is getting updates from a separate process. (I'm using IPC.)

```
  Log.i("Test1", Thread.currentThread().toString()); // Thread[Binder_3,5,main]

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Log.i("Test2", Thread.currentThread().toString()); // Thread[main,5,main]
      switch (taskId) {
      case Constants.DOWNLOAD_TASK_EXECUTED: {
        long time = prefs.getLong(Constants.LAST_UPDATED_KEY, System.currentTimeMillis());
        String msg = Utils.getLastUpdatedString(res, time, Locale.getDefault(), false);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
      }
      case Constants.DELETED_TASK_EXECUTED: {
        String msg = res.getString(R.string.delete_success);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
      }
      }
    }

  });
```

Is it necessary to call the `runOnUiThread` method and pass in a `Runnable` to display toast messages when I get updates? Or is it okay to just display them in the same thread (Binder_3)? I'm not modifying anything in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Professional Android 4 Application Development book states, "Toasts must be created and shown on the GUI thread; otherwise, you risk throwing a cross-thread exception."

Answer (score 5):

Tost Or Log Work in thread or other processes (but it's better to NOT Risk ! ) but Changing the UI must always Run in UI thread as you told with `runOnUiThread` or using `handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```